# Winetricks not installing properly through Wine on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

I'm following [this](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2957372) tutorial on installing all necessary prerequisites for league through wine as well as moving over the league files in order to have a completely functioning game.
I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04, and on stage, 2 which is this:

> Run the following lines of code in terminal:

```
`winetricks vcrun2005`    
`winetricks ie8`    
`winetricks wininet`    
`winetricks d3dx9`    
`winetricks corefonts`  
`winetricks adobeair`
```

I'm having trouble getting them to install. ie8, wininet, and adobeair all give me 404's and failed to download when I try to install them.

I also tried to follow this to fix the issue:

```
rm -fr ~/.wine
export WINEARCH=win32
export WINEPREFIX="/home/$USER/.wine"
winecfg
```

The goal of this was to convert the wine prefix to a 32 bit prefix, but this hasn't really helped at all.

Does anyone know if i'm doing something wrong, or a way to fix this?

Comment: Similar to the question on how to install the old IE4Linux package: If the files has been deleted from the server or moved without redirection and not mirrored (tricky due to copyright in some most cases) then it won't be easy to install these packages. This looks like similar, but I don't have time and the resources to test right now.

Comment: I prefer using PlayOnLinux, see: https://github.com/TheUnnamedDude/pol_league_of_legends